# jquery validate need to set the max of a range at run-time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an order page where the customer needs to only be able to order from 1 up to the number in stock.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#AddToCartForm").validate({
        rules: {
            quantity: { required: true, range: [1, $('.size_max').val()] }
        }
    });
});
```

Even though there is a hidden field with the id "size_max" and a value of 5, this returns

```
Please enter a value between 1 and NaN
```

when any number is put in the quantity field.

How can I set the upper bound of the range dynamically?

Comment: Set the value as a variable first and console.log() that value. What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned that you have a hidden field with an id, but you are using a class selector in your code. Try changing `$('.size_max')` to `$('#size_max')` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If your hidden field has an **ID** of `size_max` as you indicate, then your selector should be : `$('#size_max')`, note the selector you are using selects elements with a **class** of `size_max`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be that it is looking strictly for Integers, and that `.val()` returns a -typeof- *string*

Try doing a `parseInt( $('#size_max').val() );`